# black and white lines when I use the soften tool in texture paint

Tags: texture-painting

[image]

It appears on any object i use the soften tool on but only on this file. I tried googling a bunch and I can't seem to find the same issue. I've also tried loading this to an earlier version of blender (i use 3.1, i loaded it on 3.0) and still get the same issue. I cannot share the file, as I am using this for something for my work :(

Comment: ... but you can always delete all unnecessary objects and from issued model keep just a few faces that still provides the issue. It is always the best way to share blend file - simplify file as much as possible. Thanks ... just do not forget to pack texture if this is needed to replicate your issue.

Comment: i didnt think of that oops :')) heres the drive link to the blend file
[link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1s935JaCLRfDopxTjQ7e7dFrK3BxvRW7B/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

*There is more things that make your file weird for me, but the issue you are asking for is your Brush setup.*

---

I'm not able to replicate exactly the same since the texture in your screen is not the same with one packed in your blend.

If you try to use *Soften*. in your linked file as it is nothing is happening until I *Draw* a bit of colors, than it starts to create patterns.

Your *Brush* under *Advanced Settings is set Direction >* **Sharpen** ...

[image]